# How can buildr be instructed to generate a facted eclipse .project configuration?

Tags: eclipse, buildr, facet

I'm developing a web-project with jsp and JAX-RS. If I run `buildr eclipse`, buildr generates a simple Java project. How can I instruct buildr to generate an eclipse project facet including "Dynamic Web Module", "Java", "JavaScript", and "JAX-RS"? Indeed, "Dynamic Web Module" and "Java" would be sufficient for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by Buildr. Buildr generates a simple .project indeed, but cannot go further. There are many project natures out there, since each Eclipse plugins tend to provide their own.

You are better off changing the .project and committing it.

Comment: How can I add new jars added to the dependencies to the classpath? I assume, I have to do that manually, don't I?

Comment: Just instruct Buildr what to compile with, using compile.with.

Comment: I like eclipse's integrated tooling. Currently, I use builder only to fetch the dependencies and using the integrated eclipse toolchain and integrated tomcat. Instant deployment really works here. ;)